# MySQL: Function not returning the correct integer

Tags: mysql

We have a question regarding a function returning the wrong integer-value in MySQL. We have checked that "booked_passengers" contains the right value, 0, and it works just fine when removing that variable, meaning just returning the integer 40. But as soon as we try to subtract "booked_passengers" from it, which still should end up returning 40, it does not work.

Including the code below.

Thanks in advance! :-)

```
CREATE FUNCTION calculateFreeSeats(flightnumber INT)
RETURNS INT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE booked_passengers INT;

    SELECT BOOKED_PASSENGERS INTO booked_passengers FROM FLIGHT WHERE (flightnumber = NR);

RETURN (40-booked_passengers);

END $$
```

Answer (score 0):

When column name and local variable name interfere and there is no table alias then the variable is preferred. So your `SELECT BOOKED_PASSENGERS ...` selects variable value, not column value. Use

```
CREATE FUNCTION calculateFreeSeats(flightnumber INT)
RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE booked_passengers INT;

    SELECT FLIGHT.BOOKED_PASSENGERS INTO booked_passengers FROM FLIGHT WHERE (flightnumber = NR);

RETURN (40-booked_passengers);

END $$
```

From the other side the variable usage is obviously excess:

```
CREATE FUNCTION calculateFreeSeats(flightnumber INT)
RETURNS INT
READS SQL DATA
RETURN (SELECT 40 - BOOKED_PASSENGERS FROM FLIGHT WHERE flightnumber = NR LIMIT 1);
```